# Jquery move text within a div to a form input field

Tags: jquery, onclick

could somebody please take a look at this

http://jsfiddle.net/bloodygeese/EzkFR/1/

My aim is to on clicking the "click me" get the text contained in the "area" divs to move into the text area below - one in each space.

I have removed my failed jquery attempt at the code as I don't really know what I am doing.

If I can get this to work the next step would be to try and achieve the same thing when the "display area's are on a different page?? not sure if thats possible, I hope it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure if you want original text left behind or not

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/EzkFR/6/

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
   $('#displayarea').val(  $('#area').text() ); 
   $('#displayarea2').val(  $('#area2').text() );   
})
```

Note there is no `input type="textarea"`. It is either `input type="text"` or `<textarea></textarea>`

If you want the original text containers gone, use `remove()`

Comment: perfect! i was just going to ask for the text to be left behind. Thank you so much, and for the text area info! is there any reason why this would work if the divs and input type=text are on different pages?

Comment: different pages??  If you mean mobile pages where they are actually already existing... it would work

Comment: can't get it to work across pages, I have the divs on one html page and the form inputs on another?? any ideas

Comment: would have to use ajax to get the other page  `$.get( url, function(data){ alert($(data).find('#area1').text() }) ` as an example

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
​$("#submit").click
    (
        function()
        {
            $("#displayarea").val($("#area").text());
            $("#displayarea2").val($("#area2").text());
            $("#area").html("");            
            $("#area2").html("");
        }
        );​​​​​​​
```

Edit: using `.text` instead of `.html` because we want not any tag inside an INPUT field.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $texts = $('textarea');
var $divs = $('div');

$('#submit').click(function() {
    $divs.each(function(index) {
        $texts.get(index).value = this.innerHTML;
        $(this).remove();
    });
});​
```

[**Fixed DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/EzkFR/8/)

**Notes:**

- textarea, isn't a type of `<input>` as you wrote, it is a tag: `<textarea>`
- I cached the elements so I don't need to query the DOM multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want an extensible way to do this...

```
<div id="area" class="movable">I wish I could go down there</div>
<div id="area2" class="movable">Me too please!!</div>
</br>
<input type="textarea" id="displayarea" class="inputtable" value="" />
<input type="textarea" id="displayarea2" class="inputtable" value="" />
</br>
<div id="submit">click me</div>
</br>​

$('div#submit').click(function(e) {
    $('input.inputtable').each(function() {
        var input = $(this);
        $('div.movable').each(function() {
            var self = $(this);
            if (!self.hasClass('moved') && !input.hasClass('inputted')) {
                input.val(self.text()).addClass('inputted');
                self.addClass('moved');
            }
        });
        $('div.movable.moved').detach(); //safe to remove now that we're not looping through them.
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});​
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/EzkFR/10/